# Querying using NULL on varchar column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I pass null as a value to a string (varchar) column from linq to sql? I'm trying to query the table where some rows have NULL for a column (say, Col_A) and others have "NotNull" (string) as value.

```
string s = null;

var query = (from r in context.Table1
            where r.Col_A == s
            select r).ToList();
```

This returns 0 rows. But if I set s to "NotNull", I get the rows back as expected.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: what problems did you get from `null` ?

Comment: You need to show the code you've tried that isn't working. So long as nulls are allowed in the column in question you can just pass null

Comment: I tried setting the variable to null but the query returns 0 rows. But there are matching rows in the DB

Comment: @SamAnderson Code speaks, statements weak

Comment: If I pass in a valid string (not null), I'm getting rows back as expected.

Answer (score 4):

There is an annoying bug, where the following can work differently in some cases:

```
where x.Foo == null
```

vs

```
where x.Foo == s
```

where `s` happens to be `null` at execution. Basically, in some use-cases, it can incorrectly end up using:

```
WHERE [x].[Foo] = @p3
```

with `@p3` a `null` value, but clearly that is not sensible in ANSI compliant SQL.

I would suggest if you are doing a test where the parameter value might be `null`, special-case it and code the query with a ***literal*** `null` in the C#. I did have some code that would use an expression-visitor to apply this after-the-fact, but it is easier just to special-case `null`. So:

```
var query = // some core query

if(s == null) { query = query.Where(x => x.Foo == null); }
else { query = query.Where(x => x.Foo == s); }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, is that the only way?

Comment: In your example, you could condense to `where r.Col_A == s || (r.Col_A == null && s == null)` - the output SQL statement will look a bit strange, but it will at least avoid "the wrong type of null" issue

Comment: @Sam very few things are ever the "only way" ;p

Answer (score 0):

have you tried DBNull.Value?  That's .net's DB equivalent to null.

Comment: A lot of ORMs hide away this ugly implementation leakage detail. LINQ-to-SQL very rarely exposes this, if ever.